# Apply the quartile cuts from the train data to the test data

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, numpy, scikit-learn

Are there any existing python functions to get the quartile cuts from the train data and apply to test data.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = {'col1': np.arange(1, 100, 1)}
train = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

d1 = {'col1': np.arange(1, 200, 2)}
test = pd.DataFrame(data = d1)
```

I have about a 1000 columns in both the train and test.  Can the pandas qcut function be used to make it scalable or are there any other existing sklearn functions?

I am expecting to get the quartile for the test data (either 1,2,3 or 4) based on the bins from on the train.

Comment: what does your expected output look like?

Comment: Maybe you need this:https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.KBinsDiscretizer.html

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `retbins` argument when you `pd.qcut` the train set. Use those bins for your test set with `pd.cut`, modifying the lower and upper bounds so you can include everything.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

_, bins = pd.qcut(train.col1, q=4, retbins=True)
bins = np.concatenate(([-np.inf], bins[1:-1], [np.inf]))

# How many elements in each bin for the test set?
test.groupby(pd.cut(test.col1, bins)).size()
#col1
#(-inf, 25.5]    13
#(25.5, 50.0]    12
#(50.0, 74.5]    12
#(74.5, inf]     63
#dtype: int64
```